# ambiguous multi_select filter - AND and OR condition - javascript

Tags: javascript, yadcf

[multi_select filter](https://rawgit.com/vedmack/yadcf/master/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js) with [select2](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.js) in yadcf (datatables plugin) has a ambiguous solution for filtering.
If you have inside rows single values like

```
value1
value2
```

when you filtering you have a `OR` filtering. It shows all rows with values1 and values2.
If you set a text delimiter like a comma or multiple delimiters (using regex) multiple_select filter behaves as a `AND` condition.
Look an example for column 0: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/chcLmmps/18/)
Is possible to have a javascript function that enables or an AND condition or an OR condition according to suit your needs?

For better exposure I made a little video of what the problem is and what I expect to see in the table. 
Problem is tricky but It should not be difficult to solve with right javascript code

[VIDEO](http://nathan4000.altervista.org/tutorials/filtering.htm)

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Adding feature improvement request:

[New VIDEO](http://nathan4000.altervista.org/tutorials/checkbox.htm)

Example used in video: [Table](http://jsfiddle.net/chcLmmps/26/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the text delimiter is to help you extract values from your column into the filter, but... when you try to pick up a value from the filter and apply it to the table, you will get all the rows that your selected value is located in.

In case that you want so advanced logic to be executed when you pick up a value you should then use the `filter_type: 'custom_func'`  or `multi_select_custom_func` see how it works on [the showcase](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source.html) (its the first column) scroll down to the see the code used on that page.

---

Finally I understood your problem, while the multi select should always work as OR filter on the selected values it wasn't doing so, I have fixed it in the [latest beta 0.8.8.beta.11](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/master/beta/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js) and here is an [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chcLmmps/24/)

---

Regarding your **AND** question: You can't accomplish it with mutli select + `text_data_delimiter` image that you have a column with AAA, BBB and now your user can select AAA then BBB (that should work) but he can also select BBB and then AAA, and there is no regex that can spot the BBB, AAA as AAA, BBB (and that was just a small example)

So the best solution would be to switch between `filter_type: "multi_select"` with text_data_delimiter to (`filter_type: "multi_select"` without text_data_delimiter or `filter_type: "select"`)

And there is already a [similar issue open for that](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues/165) (not sure when I will implement it)

Comment: mmm..but is possible use for your multi_select_custom_func just a regex? example: `value1|value2|value3`. Otherwise you can add a second external filter for columns like this? https: //datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html But I want to keep your filter

Comment: For your javascript `custom_func` code of your showcase you have wrote predefined values but my case is just little different because I have no this particular need. Only to have an OR condition if I have text delimiters

Comment: Then edit your question an explain better what do you expect this OR condition to do and how you expect it to work, because I don't understand it.

Comment: It's simple to understand. You using multi_select filter with select2 for first column. If you type "Music" and "Video" you retrieve all rows with this text. But, if in your rows you have many text like this: `music, madonna` or `film, video` and in your configuration you set comma for text delimiters what happens? Typing "music" and "video" you retrieve **only** rows *that containing both music and video text* like `music, madonna, video` or `music, video` and not rows like `video, madonna` because there is no also music text in the row. Are you understand better?

Comment: Based on your example: http://jsfiddle.net/chcLmmps/18/ describe me step by stem what values you are selecting in the filter and what rows do expected to be visible in the table after you selected those values, and write all that in your question (edit it)

Comment: I update my question, look here http://nathan4000.altervista.org/tutorials/filtering.htm

Comment: Thanks for the video, finally understood the problem and fixed it, I updated my answer.

Comment: thanks for your help..now OR condition is working. Just 2 things in the same table: is possible to remove duplicate values from filter? For example `film` appears twice or more. Also `steven spielberg` appears twice. Another thing. For multi_filter is possible to choose when to use `OR` and when to use `AND` condition? Sometimes I need to use OR condition and sometimes AND condition. **Is possible to choose the operator?** This will be very useful. However +1

Comment: to remove duplicates make sure all appear with same case (only film or only Film but not both, and make sure the wont have spaces before or after the text) for example aaa,bbb and bbb,aaa is ok, while aaa, bbb is bad because there is a space before the bbb, and there can't be AND with multi select with text separator ( you can try without text separator and with setting `filter_match_mode: 'exact'` (I might fix the need of No spaces before the text with text separator usage in new future)

Comment: Ok, I try to do these little corrections and suggestions. For the moment I updated text delimiter with `,\s/,` (comma+space). Any idea to switch from *OR to AND* operator and viceversa from *AND to OR* in `multi_select` filter? Maybe you try implementing a checkbox or something similar function to enable the switching of the operators. Any fix or improvement in the future are really appreciated. I just see some benefit in your new beta yadcf.js. I solved the problem of the `onclick event` and the *jump* inside the multi_select filter now works better, thanks

Comment: Please explain how to do see the expect that **AND** filtering with multi select to work, explain how you expect to use the filter and how it will reflect on the table?

Comment: You can look new video: http://nathan4000.altervista.org/tutorials/checkbox.htm Example used: http://jsfiddle.net/chcLmmps/26/

Comment: ok, thanks for clarifications. You say for #165 https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues/165 ***"adding an ability to yadcf to replace filter type for a specific column..."*** but this solutions will not go into conflict with `bStateSave` ? you will be able to avoid this?

Comment: I think that I won't preserve the filter upon filter type changing (when you will change the filter type that column will get a reset)

Comment: ok..One last thing. Without touching your multi_filter and without touch yadcf library, is possible add a second type of filter for my table? 
I was thinking to add https://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html, but I do not know if it would conflict with the yadcf library

Comment: everything is possible, its a n open source so you can modify it as you wish